# How to localise JSON data for windows phone 8 app

Tags: json, windows-phone-8, localization

I have JSON data which has say three levels of nesting.I need to support localization of my app.I can find resources on how to create res file and support multiple languages,But they all seem to be for a single string.How do I place my nested JSON data in res file??

Comment: Why can't your json data, which just a string, become a resource value?

Comment: So you want me to put the whole JSON data as a single string?

Comment: It sounds like that is what you need. Its simple.

Comment: You could also store the filename as a string resource mapping to the correct JSON file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two simple ways to solve the problem that may work for you:

1. Depending on the size of the JSON file, you can just store the stringified JSON data as a string resource. For small amounts of data, it's a simple solution.
2. For larger files, I'd suggest instead that you store a file name/path which points at the corresponding JSON file that is appropriate for the current locale. You'd just load the file based on the file name provided in the resource at run time.